# grid representing as graph

Tags: data-structures, graph

I am thinking of a grid and suppose in the grid '#' represents that the way is blocked and '.'(dot without quotes) represents there is a way.So if A is inside the grid then he can walk inside when he found way(.)
 e.g.,

```
#######
##A####
##.#.##
##.#.##
##...##
#######
```

for the above example, A found the way and he reaches to other place like this below in picture:

```
#######
##.####
##.#A##
##.#.##
##...##
#######
```

If I am thinking this problem as a graph then How I will represent this grid as a graph ?
How to represent this as an adjacency list ?
I am new to graph just stuided BFS only, please answer in easy words

Answer (score 1):

Each cell will simply have edges to all 4 neighbouring cells. Thus every cell will appear in the adjacency lists of all 4 its neighbouring cells.

Actually you don't need to explicitly construct the graph, you can just work on the grid itself. To represent a specific node, you can just use the coordinates of the applicable cell and to go to a neighbour, you can just increase / decrease x / y by one.

I hope this is clear enough.